# Problem with building Flutter Engine on Ubuntu 18.04 with cmake

Tags: linux, flutter, cmake, raspberry-pi, clang

I am trying to build Flutter for my RPi 4 using these instructions:

https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-on-raspberry-pi-mostly-from-scratch-2824c5e7dcb1

https://blog.basyskom.com/2020/how-to-run-flutter-on-an-embedded-device/

but when I try to compile libcxxabi using:

```
cmake ../libcxxabi                    \
    -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True                     \
    -DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/sdk/sysroot                    \
    -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=False                    \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/sdk/toolchain           \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release                      \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux                       \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=ARM                    \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/sdk/toolchain/bin/clang     \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/sdk/toolchain/bin/clang++ \
    -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM                     \
    -DLIBCXXABI_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=False
```

`cmake` returns following error:

```
The C++ compiler

    "/sdk/toolchain/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/gnegon/Programs/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_6e8d2/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gnegon/Programs/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/clang++ --sysroot=/sdk/sysroot    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/gnegon/Programs/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_6e8d2
    /home/gnegon/Programs/cmake-3.19.0-rc1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/clang++ --sysroot=/sdk/sysroot CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_6e8d2 
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lstdc++
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lm
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lgcc
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lc
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lgcc
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
    /sdk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
    clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e8d2.dir/build.make:105: recipe for target 'cmTC_6e8d2' failed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_6e8d2] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gnegon/Programs/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:140: recipe for target 'cmTC_6e8d2/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_6e8d2/fast] Error 2
```

Also I don't have `/sdk/sysroot/` folder, could that cause this error?

Comment: "Also I don't have `/sdk/sysroot/` folder" - Why do you specify *sysroot* (`-DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/sdk/sysroot`) to a directory which doesn't exist?

Comment: I just copied this command from instructions.
I don't how to get this folder, I thought it would create when executing previous commands from instructions.

Comment: The missing files should be found in `/sdk/toolchain/` as part of the tools you build in the first couple of steps.  You may want to recheck that you built those correctly.  The second link in OP appear to be the better of the two directions.  Note that they recommend different directory layouts.

Comment: "The missing files should be found in /sdk/toolchain/ as part of the tools you build"
-> you mean like here:
gnegon@gnegon-VirtualBox:~$ find /sdk/toolchain/ -name crt1* 2> /dev/null
gnegon@gnegon-VirtualBox:~$ find /sdk/toolchain/ -name stdc++* 2> /dev/null
gnegon@gnegon-VirtualBox:~$ find /sdk/toolchain/ -name gcc* 2> /dev/null
gnegon@gnegon-VirtualBox:~$ 
?

Comment: "You may want to recheck that you built those correctly. "
-> previously I try to follow these instructions on Ubuntu 20.04 and got the same errors.
Then I remove everything completely (vdi and machine in VBox) and set up again, this time Ubuntu 18.04 on my VirtualBox from scratch.

Comment: Every `cmake`, `make` and `make install` executed without errors.